# Get work info of user using facebook id or name

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, graph-api-explorer

Making the following query on facebook graph api explorer `search?q=CEO%20Microsoft&type=user` produces the following result as shown. [image: here] Is there a way to get the work information of someone using the username or id? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to get the work information of someone using the username or id?

Of course not.

You can not get this kind of data for just any arbitrary user.

The user has to login to your app and grant it the necessary permission.

---

It’s called privacy, you know.

Comment: Just to be sure we are all in the same page. I was talking about a user who has his profile public not private